# How to determine if it is the first or not in mapping an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using React in typeScript.

I want to change the background color of array[0] by mapping the acquired array data.

Is there a way to determine if it is the first in an array?

This is arrayList

> Array:[{"createDt":"2022/12/27", "status":"aaa","operatorId":"001"},
> {"createDt":"2022/12/28", "status":"bbb","operatorId":"002"}]

```
in JSX

Array.map((item, index) => {
let bgColorHeader = '#FFCCCC'
// ★ I want to change the background color only at the beginning of the array.<br>
 let bgColorHeader = '';
 let bgColorData = '';
 let bgColorHeaderLatest = '#BEFF97'
 let bgColorDataLatest= '#DCFDD8'
 let bgColorHeaderOther = '#808080'
 let bgColorDataOther = '#D3D3D3'
 index === 0 ? bgColorHeader = bgColorHeaderLatest : gColorHeaderOther;
 index === 0 ? bgColorData = bgColorDataLatest : bgColorDataOther;
 return (
  <TableBody key={index}>
   <TableRow>
    <TableCell
     sx = {{backgroundColor: {bgColorHeader} }}
    >
    <TableCell
     sx = {{backgroundColor: {bgColorData} }}
    >
 )
})
```

Comment: Please provide some code so others can understand it.

Comment: @PriyenMehta
Yes! Updated!

Comment: You have already implemented the solution, but why have you nested the assignment? Also don't use index as key.

Comment: @pilchard
Since there was no unique key in the retrieved data, I used index as a key...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the index

```
array.map((element, index) => { /* ... */ })
```

If index = 0 then this is the first element of array

```
let bgColorHeader = index === 0 ? '#FFFFFF' : '#FFCCCC'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this
`let bgColorHeader = index === 0 ? '#FFFFFF' : '#FFCCCC'`

added to ur code

```
Array.map((item, index) => {
let bgColorHeader = index === 0 ? '#FFFFFF' : '#FFCCCC'
 return (
  <TableBody key={index}>
   <TableRow>
    <TableCell
     sx = {{backgroundColor: {bgColorHeader} }}
    >
 )
})
```